# How do I clone a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the function `formatHours()` below, I am trying to assign `newHours` to `selectedLocation.data.hours` (an object)

I am using the spread operator to clone the object, so that when the function finishes `selectedLocation.data.hours` remains the same, but it doesn't. After this function runs, `selectedLocationd.data.hours` is now equal to `newHours`.

**formatHours():**

```
const formatHours = () => {
    // ERROR: trying to clone selectedLocation.data.hours, but not working
    const newHours = { ...selectedLocation.data.hours };

    // loop through all hours and convert them to javascript date with .toDate()
    for (const hour in newHours) {
      newHours[hour][0] = newHours[hour][0].toDate();
      newHours[hour][1] = newHours[hour][1].toDate();
    }

    // set hours state with updated hours
    setHours(newHours);
  };
```

Here's what `selectedLocation.data.hours` looks like BEFORE passing it through `formatHours()`:

(object of arrays of Firebase Firestore timestamps)

[image]

Here's what `selectedLocation.data.hours` looks like AFTER passing it through `formatHours()`:

(object of arrays of Javascript Date objects)

[image]

**NOTE:** `selectedLocation.data.hours` should stay the same before and after the function, but doesn't. I must be missing something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the `newHours[hour]` array (which mutates the object currently in state/props), create an *entirely new array* at that location, with the properties you need:

```
// Shallow clone newHours
const newHours = { ...selectedLocation.data.hours };
// Reassign each property; it'll affect the clone, not the original
for (const [hour, arr] of Object.entries(newHours)) {
  newHours[hour] = [
    arr[0].toDate(),
    arr[1].toDate(),
    arr[2]
  ];
}
```

Another method, with `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const newHours = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(selectedLocation.data.hours).map(([hour, arr]) => (
        [ // return an entry array
            hour, // key in new object
            [ // value in new object
                arr[0].toDate(),
                arr[1].toDate(),
                arr[2]
            ]
        ]
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do that, but you can do this

```js
    const newHours = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedLocation.data.hours));
```

This will deep clone the object.